# Figuring out OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

in Symfony2, using Doctrine, I have two entities: Job and User.

I have followed the doctrine docs and figured out how to map ManyToOne and OneToMany relationships.

This is my user class:

```
   /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        protected $id;

        //it has all the necessary fields (username, pass and so on) and the ones related to Job entity:


        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="user")
         * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\Job")
         **/
        protected $jobs;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->jobs = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @return ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getJobs()
        {
            return $this->jobs;
        }

        /**
         * @param $jobs
         */
        public function setJobs($jobs)
        {
            $this->jobs = $jobs;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addJob(Job $job)
        {
            $this->jobs->add($job);
            $job->setUser($this);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function removeJob(Job $job)
        {
            $this->jobs->removeElement($job);
        }
```

On the other side, I have Job entity written like this:

```
    /**
     * Job
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="hr_job")
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repo\JobRepository")
     * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
     */
    class Job
    {

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @Type("integer")
         * @ORM\Column(name="job_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        //other properties go here (title, description and email)

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="jobs")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
         * @Expose
         * @Type("AppBundle\Entity\User")
         **/
        protected $user;

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getUser()
        {
            return $this->user;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $user
         */
        public function setUser($user)
        {
            $this->user = $user;
        }
```

In a controller, I am adding a Job for a logged in user and it gets inserted just fine. It has a user_id foreign key that relates to an appropriate user.

But, the problem occurs when I try to get all jobs added by that user.

For some reason, $user->getJobs() is always empty. It behaves really strange. I tried dumping it in php, I got nothing. I tried dumping it in twig, and I get PersistentCollection object that doesn't mean a thing to me.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: This is my controller code. Serialization is properly done.

```
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $jobJSON = $request->getContent();

        $loggedInUser = $this->getUser();

        $jobClassObject = $serializer->deserialize($jobJSON, "AppBundle\Entity\Job", "json");

        $jobClassObject->setUser($loggedInUser);

        //$loggedInUser->addJob($jobClassObject);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($jobClassObject);
        $em->flush();
```

Comment: Why your setters return nothing?

Answer (score 2):

[In the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side) you can read that:

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.

And [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) in detail:

> To fully understand this, remember how bidirectional associations are maintained in the object world. There are 2 references on each side of the association and these 2 references both represent the same association but can change independently of one another. Of course, in a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association are properly maintained by the application developer (**that’s his responsibility**). Doctrine needs to know which of these two in-memory references is the one that should be persisted and which not. This is what the owning/inverse concept is mainly used for.

So it is your responsibility to take care of the inverse side, meaning you have to **also update the inverse side** when you set the owning side:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $user
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $user->addJob($this);
}
```

Comment: I've read that part of documentation several times, and by all means it should work. I will update the question with Controller code. I have updated my setUser method with your code, but now I get Bad Gateway nginx error.

Comment: Did you try adding `addJob` in this method? I am 99% sure it will work.

Comment: And remove `$job->setUser($this);` from the `addJob` method, you should set from owning side...

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't get it, why do I even call addJob method when in fact it does not add job to a user's collection of created jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement addJob() / removeJob() methods in your User entity class.

Comment: I have found this example: http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/more-on-one-to-manymany-to-one-associations-in-doctrine-2/ but there is no use case that I need. This is really frustrating. How do I access the list of jobs for a particular user, without creating the separate query?

Comment: Just join that table. You can do it like this (assuming the code below is in repository class): 
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')->select('user, jobs')->leftJoin('user.jobs');

It'll let you have jobs for each user without extra query.

Comment: I know I could do that, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. What is the point of having inverse side if I am not able to use it.

Comment: I don't get it. You are trying to avoid a join in query but you need the jobs list. What is exactly your flow?

Comment: Let's walk through all the steps. You get a request, retrieve json string from it. Then you create Job instance with Serializer's deserialize method, add current logged in user to Job object, persist job, flush. And you expect the logged user to have just created Job in jobs collection. Right?

Comment: And a guy in second answer made a good suggestion. I think it should work.

Comment: yes, I though it would be enough to have Jobs collection for a particular user. I though that was something that doctrine would do by itself. Otherwise, I don't get the point of AddJob method. $job->setUser($user) works perfectly. I guess I'm kinda lost here and not used to using Doctrine.

Comment: Sure, I can create a method in user repository, something like getUserPostedJobs(), and use createQuery builder, but is that really necessary?